# Failed to initialize Integration Runtime (Self-hosted) node components

Tags: azure, components, runtime, integration, azure-virtual-machine

I am trying to install integration runtime(self-hosted) in Virtual machine. When i enter authentication key , The registration key is recognized on the runtime  but then when I click "Finish" it just stays stuck in "initializing...." for a long time and then throws the error.[enter image description here][2]

[error_img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6dSq.png)

Comment: Is this issue fixed on your side? If so, please remove this thread or show your solution.

Comment: @Nancy Yes its fixed i have not done anything .I have reinstalled IR then it was working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just post the solution in the comment as an answer.

In this case, reinstall integration runtime(self-hosted) is to fix this issue.